# how to pass jenkins param in pom while running tests locally

Tags: java, jenkins

there is a parameter called filename which is passed from jenkins and thats declared in pom as
${Dfilename}

which works fine when we run selenium tests via jenkins but if manually harcode it as
test
null pointer is throw as the value is null. please help

Comment: Did you have a look at the Maven documentation yet? Doesn't it describe a way to either pass parameters from the command line or via a profile, e.g. something like `mvn install -DDfilename=whatever`?

Comment: I want to pass via POM file only

Comment: So the pom.xml is only used for local builds? Could you add the files and the stack trace you're getting?

Comment: I am changing pom.xml file to run tests in local. Cant I harcode that field in pom file?

Comment: Did you look at how to define properties in the pom? If should be something like `<properties><Dfilename>whatever</Dfilename></properties>` (this assumes the property name is `Dfilename` as per what you've posted).

Answer (score 1):

If passing the value through the command line isn't an option, like you say in the comments, you can use a Maven Profile to set the property value. There's a number of ways to maintain and activate profiles. You can place them in the `pom.xml` itself.

This [guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html#which-areas-of-a-pom-can-be-customized-by-each-type-of-profile-w) lists quite a few use cases.

Comment: Cant I hardcode the value of ${Dfilename} in POM file while running in local?

Comment: You could hardcode it through the [properties section](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties) but then you may have to remember to override it everywhere else. This may be fine depending of that the variable represents. If it's a sensible default, you could just do that. Profiles are more flexible that way in that they can be easily activated conditionally (implicitly or explicitly).